# Passing a single argument to a function that has default values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript function that looks like:

`my_app.api.index = function(event, page = 1, sort = "last_name", desc = true, limit = 9999)`

So, this is using the wonderful default values we get with ES6. What I would like to be able to do is call this function, passing only ONE of the values...or two, or three, however many, without having to pass all of them.

Something like:

`my_app.api.index(sort: sortField);`

The ideal behavior would be that it uses the default values for the other arguments, but it uses the passed value for the named parameter. What is the syntax for this? Is it even possible?

Comment: See a bunch of different choices here: [Exporting function with options](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200229/nodejs-module-exports-export-multiple-functions-vs-exporting-a-single-function/200231#200231) including the idea option for this which is taking a single object as an argument and passing the desired properties only.

Comment: You can have a look at this : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/elegant-patterns-in-modern-javascript-roro-be01e7669cbd

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object instead. [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will overwrite the values you've specified in the arguments, and all others will stay default:

```
my_app.api.index = function(options) {
    options = Object.assign({
       page: 1,
       sort: "last_name",
       desc: true,
       limit: 9999
    }, options);
```

Call it with:

```
my_app.api.index({sort: sortField});
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the function such that it accepts a single *object* (with default object values), instead of an argument list. Destructure the object in the arguments themselves for syntax brevity:

```js
const myfn = ({ event='someevent', page=1, sort='lastName' }) => {
  console.log('fn running with ' + event + ' ' + page + ' ' + sort);
};
myfn({ sort:'firstName' });
```

Comment: Both your answer and FrankerZ work, I just went with this to maintain the syntax I've already got in place. I'll accept as soon as I can, thank you!